# Is it possible to use different CSS libraries for different components in our react website?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, semantic-ui

**For example**, I have 3 components==> *Home, About, Contact*.

Is it possible to use material ui css library for Home component, semantic ui css library for About component and bootstrap for Contact Component.

If yes, then How?

Comment: Yes, but why would you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, *I think the better question is if you should.*
Mixing frameworks would likely lead to in inconsistent UX. That's something normally avoided for non-technical reasons.

Still, sometimes you need to transition things slowly, and might have different parts of your software look different.

When you're certain you actually want to mix different ui frameworks, just follow the regular 'get-started' guides for those frameworks.

here's a [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-forked-t22rbb?file=/index.tsx) with both a mui-button and a bootstrap-button

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { Button as BootstrapButton } from "react-bootstrap";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <BootstrapButton variant="primary">Primary</BootstrapButton>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />);
```

Comment: Thank you  Lars for explaining with code.